# Is it possible to run the npx tool to execute packages in Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-web-app-service, npx

Is it possible to run the npx tool to execute packages in Azure App service (Web application).

I am using:

- node: v10.19.0
- npm: v6.13.4

If i browse to nodejs on my local machine I can see the npx.cmd tool but if i do the same in azure i don't see it.

I tried running **npm i -g npx** which installed it, but to some random local appdata folder.

Comment: If possible, it is recommended to choose the Linux operating system when creating a web app. Due to various restrictions, it is currently not possible to install npm globally on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After my testing, I saw that under the windows operating environment, it is impossible to install with `npm i -g npx`.

But if you need to use `npx`, you can choose the Linux operating system.

[image]